# How to assign the value to templateUrl object in directive

Tags: angularjs

I have custom directive..

```
<users stats="stats"></users>
```

In controller, I have assigned stats value like

```
$scope.stats = "10";
```

Then I have written custom directives and get a scope object(stats)

```
directive.scope = {stats:'='})
directive.transclude = true;

directive.templateUrl = "templates/partials/users_stats.html";
    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs){
            attrs.noEmpl = scope.stats;
    }
```

Then i have noEmpl modal in users_stats.html file

```
<span class="info-box-number">{{noEmpl}}</span>
```

Here value is not assigning

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mdingalla/p13d44xz/8/

Comment: The only object that can bind with your view is `$scope`.  `attrs` is a simple object containing the string value passed to all its attributes. So it will have something like `{stats : 'stats'}`. You want to bind with `{{stats}}`, or any other properties of `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
directive.templateUrl = "templates/partials/users_stats.html";
directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.noEmpl = scope.stats;
}
```

then in html

```
<span class="info-box-number">{{noEmpl}}</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mdingalla/p13d44xz/8/ - jsfiddle

Comment: You dont use `$scope` in your view, it already looks up against the scope.

Comment: If i print scope, stats is there inside. But if i use scope.stats, it is showing as undefined